# Looking for a server side way to detect abandoned forms

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, apache, session

I have a PHP/Apache form that's displayed to users. Identifying when the form has been shown and validated is easy, but I'm having a hard time detecting when it has been ignored.

A JavaScript heartbeat on the client side, then marking the session as abandoned when the heartbeat stops was a possibility. This seems like a bad idea since not all users have Javascript enabled (accessibility for screen readers, etc.)

Expiring cookies seem unreliable given the prevalence of cookie blockers and privacy rules.

It's also possible that I'm barking up the wrong tree.

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is to track how many **people** look at the form then leave without ever interacting with it. While I could track how many times it's been shown, a lot of the traffic is bots.

Also, for those humans that started to fill in the form, I'm trying to track the session through to completion.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd say the best you can do is: page loads - form submits.

Comment: A passive captcha can distinguish between people and bots pretty accurately.

Comment: When you serve a form page, mark some database with "formserved".  When you receive the user's response for that form, remove that mark.

Comment: I think many of these concerns are improperly conflated. A request for a resource (the form URL) is not equal to **intent** to fill (or even view) the form, and it's certainly not equal to an **attempt**.  Without a cooperating client (JS), this objective seems like a non-starter to me. If you accept that you can't measure a (potentially large) slice of user behavior, and just work with what's accessible to measure, then I think you'll be able to work toward a solution.